# Unable to locate element on Instagram page with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, instagram

Using selenium with Python I cannot identify an element on the page.
When I run the code the first time, I get the web page, but once the find_element is executed I get the error "Unable to locate element".
I noticed that if I run the find_element again without reopening the page I get the element without any error.

Below are the failed attempts:

- I inserted several await
- I tried using presense_of_all_elements_located
- I tried using element_to_be_clickable
- I tried searching for the element with XPATH, TAG_NAME, etc (but I always find it only on the second iteration of the find_element command)

What I am trying to do:

- I tried to print out all the XPATH elements:

```
ele = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id]')
for x in ele:
    print(x.tag_name, x.get_attribute('id'))
```

and noticed that they are different between the first iteration (where the instagram page is also opened) and the second iteration (where I run the code while leaving the page open). And actually the body where the desired element is found is only found with the second iteration.
I read that maybe the problem is with the presence of iframes within the page, I don't understand how to identify the right iframe and how to select it.

Can anyone help me understand why I can't find the elements on the page without having to run the code again?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram heavily relies on dynamic content loaded through JavaScript. If elements are loaded asynchronously or after the initial page load, you might need to wait for the elements being present in the DOM.So put some wait command after navigation.

```
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // Find all elements with an 'id' attribute using XPath
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id]"));
```